# iterate through array in Java and compare two results

Tags: java, arrays, rest

Given and Array of Strings, such as:

```
userMail usermail = new userMail();
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Where the Object userMail is defined as such:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class userMail {
    public userMail(){

    }

    public List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(List<String> email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

So here is where I am lost:
Given an email address from a client, iterate through an array and find it. If it exists, then return some data that is associated with this email address and use REST to post it back to the client.

Even a high-level concept would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You will want to use something like a `for` loop to iterate. `if` you match a condition, you will return that related data.  If you fail to find anything in that loop, you will know it isn't there and will return some error code.

Comment: I think you want to use some kind of `Map`, not an array or a `List`.  The keys in the map would be the email addresses, and the values would be some kind of object that represents the rest of the data that you want to return.  Read up on the `Map` interface.

Comment: Your `List<String>` should probably be something like `List<YourEmailObject> emailObjects` then you could run an enhanced for in a getter method such as: `public int getEmaildId(String emailAddy) { for (YourEmailObject emailObject : emailObjects) { if (emailObject.email.equals(emailAddy) return emailObject.getID(); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use HashMap or any Map construct which will clear the hastle of setting up a search algorithm.

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HashMap<String,String> xdr = new HashMap<String, String>();
    xdr.put("bdx@atr.com", "Border line Statement");
    System.out.println(xdr.get("pdf"));//output returned is null
            String valx = xdr.get("bdx@atr.com");
    String valy = xdr.get("pdf");
    if(valy == null)
        System.out.println("This is null value" + valy);
    if(valx == null)
        System.out.println(valx);
}
```

in case the key is not found null is returned. you can check the value returned against null to proceed further.

> then return some data that is associated with this email address

you can even store this data you want to return as the value store in the HashMap for the key.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public email checkForEmail(testEmail)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < emailList.length-1; emailList--) //searches through list of emails
    {
        if(emailList[x].equals(testEmail)) //if current index position equals email you search for
            return emailList[x]; //return that email
    }
    return null; //returns null if the email address wasn't contained
}
```

You can edit the if statement to compare whatever variable of the email you chose.

Comment: Are you assuming that the `equals` method of whatever class `testEmail` is has been overridden?  If not, why wouldn't you just use `contains` on the list?

Comment: unless I am incorrect contains is less efficient than this for loop

Comment: Actually, apart from the compile errors, and the fact that you've used `equals` the opposite way around, this is pretty much the same as what the `indexOf` method of `ArrayList` does; which `contains` calls.  But it's always worth avoiding rewriting code that already exists in the JDK.